# how to pass nullable value sql server report

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, reporting-services

Using Odbc connection am creating reports in sql server report for postgres database. I have issue in passing nullable value parameter although the query is working fine in query deginer but not working while running the server. my query

```
Select * 
from "FF"."Rpt_vEventReportpart1" a 
where a."CallType" is null or a."CallType"= (COALESCE(?,a."CallType"))
```

Comment: How is it _not working_?

Comment: thats what am asking i donno?

Comment: I mean what does or does not happen? Describe the problem.

Comment: while passing null parameter through ssrs query designer its working.But not working while clicking run button

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess. Try it:

```
where 
    a."CallType" is null or 
    ? is null or
    a."CallType" = ?
```